# Change tracking entities from multiple sources in Domain Driven Design

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

I am currently in the process of developing a a rather big web application and is using domain driven design.

I have currently run into some trouble with tracking changes to my Product entity. The thing is, products are constructed partly from data in SQL Azure, partly from data in Azure Table Storage.  If certain properties are changed, I will need to persist to both, other changes only to one.

As a result I can not use NHibernate or Entity Framework for tracking changes. For instance the Price argument on the

```
    public void AddPrice(Price price)
```

method on the Product entity must be persisted to SQL Azure, calculations on a range of prices will take place and the result will be saved to Azure Table Storage.

How would you solve this?

Thoughts:

1) I thought about implementing my own change tracker based on Castle.DynamicProxy, but that seems rather tedious.

2) Implement events internally in the domain entities. This is not a good thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scattering one entity across several persistent stores might not be a good idea. To be more precise, it might mean that it's not one and the same entity and could be split up in smaller, more accurately designed parts instead.

> calculations on a range of prices will take place

Are you sure these calculations affect the Product entity and should be handled by the same NHibernate/EF session used in the Product repository ? Since they have to be stored elsewhere, don't they make up a first class notion in the ubiquitous language, resulting in a separate entity with a persistence logic of its own ?

See http://ayende.com/blog/153699/ask-ayende-repository-for-abstracting-multiple-data-sources

Comment: Thanks for making it clear to me. The reason for using Azure Table Storage is for performance reasons. What I will do, is always use SQL Azure for persisting my domain model and have an infrastructure service of some sorts create the table storage entities based on SQL Azure. This also works perfectly in conjuction with the CQRS pattern (http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html).

Answer (score 0):

What do ORMs do? They take a copy of the data that's used to restore your object into its current state, just before they hand you a reference to the object. When behavior has been applied to the object and you're asking to persist it, the ORM will compare its copy of the data to the data currently inside the object and flush changes accordingly. Why not do the same? The only difference is that not all detected changes will be flushed to the same datastore.

HTH.

BTW, any concurrency going on here?